# Chat I wrote snaps to top on Safari - sets scrollTop to 0

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, chat, scrolltop

I'm having an issue with a chat I've written. I wrote the following code so that it would scroll to the bottom when the user either hadn't touched the chat or was scrolled near the bottom.  It works fine on Chrome but on Safari, it will always set the attribute scrollTop to 3 when a new entry is added. It also will randomly snap to the top after a while even if there had been no entry. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
function writeChat(elem) {  
const chatty = document.getElementById('chat');  
const nDiv = newLine();  
const chInfo = window.getComputedStyle(chatty, null);  
nDiv.appendChild(elem);  
const total = parseInt(chInfo.getPropertyValue('height')) + chatty.scrollTop + 18;  
if(total >= chatty.scrollHeight || hasScrolled == false) {  
    chatty.appendChild(nDiv);  
    setTimeout(function(){ chatty.scrollTop = 1000000; }, 0.15);  
} else {  
    chatty.appendChild(nDiv);  
}};  

function newLine(cls) {  
const nDiv = document.createElement('div');  
if(cls) {  
    nDiv.className = cls;  
} else {  
    nDiv.className = "chatEntry";  
}  
return nDiv;  };
```

css for the chat div:

```
position: relative;
overflow-y: auto;
word-wrap: break-word;
height: 89%;
width: 98%;
font-size: 2vw;
padding: 1% 2%;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

A gif of how it looks on Safari:
[On Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAS31.gif)

A gif of how it looks on Chrome:
  [On Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogR2m.gif)